# ReactiveUI - master/detail binding - de-select current record

Tags: xaml, reactiveui

I'm trying to implement master/detail using `ReactiveUI` for a list of attachments. Here's a simplified version of my view model:

```cs
public class AttachmentsViewModel : ReactiveObject, ISupportsActivation
 {
     private ReactiveList<Attachment> _attachments;
     public ReactiveList<Attachment> Attachments
     {
         get => _attachments;
         set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged( ref _attachments, value );
     }

     private IReactiveDerivedList<AttachmentViewModel> _attachmentViewModels;
     public IReactiveDerivedList<AttachmentViewModel> AttachmentViewModels
     {
         get => _attachmentViewModels;
         set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _attachmentViewModels, value );
     }

     private AttachmentViewModel _selected;
     public AttachmentViewModel Selected
     {
         get => _selected;
         set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged( ref _selected, value );
     }
}
```

In my view, I have a `ListView` and a set of controls  to let the user edit properties (e.g. a `TextBox` called `AttachmentName`). Here's what I would do in the view, based on the view model above:

```cs
public class AttachmentsView : IViewFor<AttachmentsViewModel>
{
    public AttachmentsView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.WhenActivated( d => {
            this.OneWayBind( ViewModel, vm => vm.AttachmentViewModels, v => v.List.ItemsSource ).DisposeWith( d );
            this.Bind( ViewModel, vm => vm.Selected, v => v.List.SelectedItem ).DisposeWith( d );

            this.Bind( ViewModel, vm => vm.Selected.Name, v => v.AttachmentName.Text ).DisposeWith( d );
        }
    }
}
```

All of this works as expected, when I click on a row in the `ListView`, the controls in my panel change accordingly.

However, when I de-select the currently selected item, `AttachmentName` still displays the old value (instead of showing nothing). I'm assuming that the linq expression does not fire the property changed event because the binding is more than one property deep?

Is there any way around this? Maybe there's another way to achieve master-detail navigation/editing?

Comment: I've currently worked around this issue by doing the binding in xaml (with the same linq expression). I did this by setting the `DataContext` of a parent control to `Selected`

Answer (score 0):

You can observe in your view the SelectedItem and change the AttachmentName:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ViewModel.Selected).Where(x => x == null)
    .Subscribe(selected => AttachmentName.Text == "").DisposeWith(d);
```

Comment: Yes. But I would like 2-way binding :)

Comment: If AttachmentName is Label, you can not bind in two way mode with an Attachment. If AttachmentName is Entry, you will need to filter list and change Selected in your ViewModel